# Modify beamer sectionnavigation

Tags: beamer

I'm using warsaw theme in Latex,  and I want to know how to modify sectionnavigation, in order to use bold police for current section instead of lighted one. And I don't want to make other sections in navigation bar looks shaded.

Answer (score 4):

Change the section in head/foot and section in head/foot shaded templates:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot}{\hfill\bfseries\insertsectionhead}
\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}{\hfill\insertsectionhead}

\begin{document} 

\section{Test section one}
\begin{frame} test one\end{frame}
\section{Test section two}
\begin{frame} test two\end{frame}
\section{Test section three}
\begin{frame} test three\end{frame}
\section{Test section four}
\begin{frame} test four\end{frame}
\section{Test section five}
\begin{frame} test five\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

A zoomed image of the navigation bar:

[image]

Notice, however, that with these settings it's hard to tell the difference between the current section and other sections in the navigation bar.