# Combining Madrid and Szeged theme

Tags: beamer, themes

I like to use the Madrid theme in beamer for its simplicity. In my current presentation I would like to add a thin navigation bar (like in the Szeged theme) as a feature just above the Madrid theme. Can one achieve this in a simple way or is it better to use a different theme all together?

I thought this would be an answered question on stackexchange, but the only answers I (below) did not seem to help:
[Modify beamer sectionnavigation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130833/modify-beamer-sectionnavigation)
[Omit/delete second bar under the navigation bar in szeged theme?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42898/omit-delete-second-bar-under-the-navigation-bar-in-szeged-theme)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Szeged` theme uses the headline from the `miniframes` outer theme:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}

\begin{document}

\section{sec1}
\subsection{sub1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
content...
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is possible to Combine Madrid and Warsaw theme? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Student Sure it is possible - but you would have to ask a question describing which elements of which theme you want.